# Django unittesting fulltext search

Tags: mysql, django, unit-testing, full-text-search

I want to test MySQL InnoDB fulltext search as part of my Django unittest, e.g.:

```
object__search='abc'
```

But the search fails in the unittest.
The same search works in Django code - it just fails in the unittest

Comment: add your test case's code to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MySQL fulltext index is only updated after DB commit.
I assume you are using the Django TestCase which creates a transaction and does not commit.
Instead, use TransactionTestCase, or roll your own derived TestCase
NOTE: TransactionTestCase clears all data from the database at the end of the test.